# How to set IPMetric of IPV6 in WMI C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I would like to set the IPMetric of the IPV6 in my PC using WMI and C#. I believe I need to use SetIPConnectionMetric method of the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class. But when I open the adapter setting in my PC the IPMetric of IPV4 and IPV6 are 2 separate setting, whereas in the class there is no mention if this is a IPV4 metric change or a IPV6 metric change. Is there a way to set the IPV6 IPMetric in the PC?

[IPMetric in my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UTzi.png)